# Dynamic updating table in PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyqt4

Not so long ago I created an app in `Tkinter` for a "How long can you hold yoursefl" challenge. The main thing is that you have to hang in a rope as long as you can. The program has a stopwatch and a list below it with the time of the participants. When a person start, I start the stopwatch and he can see his place in the list dynamically. He starts from the last position with `00:00:00` time and move up as he hands more. 3 players above the participant and 2 below are shown.

In `Tkinter` I used 6 `Label` widgets and dynamically updated them. This was good so far and worked perfectly but I wanted to add more functions and I read a lot about `PyQt` so I wanted to rewrite the code in `PyQt`

So far everything is good, I created the stopwatch, an entry field to type the name of the participant.

For the dynamic list I am thinking about to use a borderless table widget with 3 columns and 6 rows. Each column will correspond to:

```
Placement --> Name --> Time
```

Is there any better or simpler way to achieve this? Should I stick with some static text widget and don't bother with table?

I attach a screenshot about the working `Tkinter` application. This is how I imagine the `Qt` one as well.

[image]